# Sending state data down to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Many similar posts came up about this topic but none of them makes sense in the context of my application, so I am posting this, let me know if it is a duplicate and that it has an answer already.

A `Circle` component, renders a simple `div` element with `onMouseMove` event handler. Calls the `UpdateCoords` function which sends the position of the pointer on that element which is stored as a `state` :

```
this.state = {
    position: {x: null, y: y}
};
```

I have a parent component `Main` which renders the `Circle` component, now I think I need to use the values of `state` from the `Circle` component, but I am not quite sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to pass data from parent to child you use props and when from child to parent use callback function.

Main Component

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      position: { x: null, y: null}
    };
  }
  
  updateCoords = (x , y) => {
    this.setState({
      position: {
        x, y
      }
    });
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
        <div className='main-container'>
            <Circle mouseMove={ this.updateCoords }/>
            <pre>
              <p> x - y:  {this}</p>
            </pre>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Circle Component

```js
class Circle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          position: {x: null, y: null}
      }
      
      this.updateCoords = this.updateCoords.bind( this );
    }
    
    updateCoords( evt ){
        let x = evt.clientX;
        let y = evt.clientY;
    
        this.setState({
            position: {
                x: x,
                y: y,
            }
        });
        
        this.props.mouseMove(x, y);
    
        console.log("Clicked");
    }
  
    render() {
      return( 
          <div className="circle" onMouseMove={ this.updateCoords }>
              <span>
              x: {this.state.position.x}, y: {this.state.position.y}
              </span>
          </div> 
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. you can check the complete code here: https://codepen.io/depy/pen/RQxQpp?editors=1010

Comment: You need to have updateCoords method in your main component which will receive the props and you can update your state.

Comment: @DeepakKamat Updated the answer with sample code. I have used ES6 in the function updateCoords, if you don't want that convert it to ES5.

Comment: Awesome! It's working now. Thanks for the help, this helped me understand what's going on.